# Retrieve one record for each column irrespective of number records in the table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I want to select one record with two joins.
I have following query:

```
$this->db
        ->select('vehicle.idvehicle, vehicle.mark, vehicle.model, vehicle.type, vehicle.author_id, users.nick, photos.name')
        ->from('xxxxxsld_auto.vehicle')
        ->join('users', 'vehicle.author_id = users.userid')
        ->join('photos', 'vehicle.idvehicle = photos.vehicle_id')
        ->get()
        ->result_array();
```

It works fine, but if I have more photos in DB, I get more more records, it depends of photos record.
What should I do to receive one record for each vehicle irrespective of number record in photos table?

**Edit:** `LIMIT` and `DISTINCT` didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` and `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to pick one photo, if you want all the photos you can just use `GROUP_CONCAT(photos.name) AS photo` and you can get all the photos name by comma seperated list ,i have used `->group_by('vehicle.idvehicle');` so for one vehicle group all the photos will be merged by comma but as in your question you stated you need the one photo so i used the `SUBSTRING_INDEX`  you can also get the latest photo by using the ORDER by in `GROUP_CONCAT` if photo id is auto incremented like `SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(photos.name ORDER BY photo.id DESC),',',1) AS photo`

```
$this->db
        ->select("vehicle.idvehicle, vehicle.mark,
         vehicle.model, vehicle.type, vehicle.author_id, users.nick, 
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(photos.name),',',1) AS photo,",FALSE)
        ->from('xxxxxsld_auto.vehicle')
        ->join('users', 'vehicle.author_id = users.userid')
        ->join('photos', 'vehicle.idvehicle = photos.vehicle_id')
        ->group_by('vehicle.idvehicle'); 
        ->get()
        ->result_array();
```

Or just use group by

```
$this->db
        ->select("vehicle.idvehicle, vehicle.mark,
         vehicle.model, vehicle.type, vehicle.author_id, users.nick, 
         photos.name,",FALSE)
        ->from('xxxxxsld_auto.vehicle')
        ->join('users', 'vehicle.author_id = users.userid')
        ->join('photos', 'vehicle.idvehicle = photos.vehicle_id')
        ->group_by('vehicle.idvehicle'); 
        ->get()
        ->result_array();
```

**Edit** From the comments you stated you need all photos so be aware of that fact the `GROUP_CONCAT` has a default limit of 1024 characters to concatenate but this can be increased by following the [**manual**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: Awesome! I wanted to select all photos for each vehicle but I didn't know how to do it. THANKS :)